# nodejs execsync command failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, extendscript

I am trying to run a `execSync` file:

```
try {
    const child_process = require("child_process")
    child_process.execSync('"C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CC 2019/Photoshop.exe" Z:/myfile.jsx', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error here");
    }
})
    .on('close', function (code, signal) {console.log('go to next step')})
} catch (err) {
    err.stdout;
    err.stderr;
    err.pid;
    err.signal;
    err.status;
}
```

The script ran but gave me exit code of 1:

```
Error: Command failed: "C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CC 2019/Photoshop.exe" Z:/myfile.jsx
```

How could I get rid of this.

Comment: So there is no err? Neither does it jump into the catch section?

Comment: You are trying to open .jsx file with photoshop.? Why would you do that?

Comment: @Gary : what? seriously? Have you read about photoshop scripting ,

Comment: No, I didn't know .jsx opening from photoshop. I haven't seen anything like this. If you say it works then your command to open the file is wrong.thats the error. Try this in the terminal and check your command to see if it works

Comment: Sorry, I was not being rude, Yes i tried it in command prompt and it worked

Comment: Hmmm... The documentation says the function returns a buffer of command output. It is not supposed to be taking a call back as per the docs for 11.x  `child_process.execSync(command[, options])`  `Returns: <Buffer> | <string> The stdout from the command.` Can you try assigning the result instead of the call back. I am not on my desk but if you can check this it will be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by writing a photoshop exit code inside the jsx file and it closed the photoshop and given me a success code